# flutter : The argument type 'List<UpdateMenuModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UpdateMenuModel'

Tags: flutter, dart, model

how to fix this Model issue.

I know This is updateMenuDatabaseHelper.insert(data); storing as UpdateMenuModel thats why I am getting error.
But how to fix it. I am not understanding.

### //// updateMenuDatabaseHelper.insert(data); This is my SQFLITE database functionality where I want to add

```
List<UpdateMenuModel> data = [];
data.add( UpdateMenuModel(
              productId: menuData["ProductId"],
              productTitle: menuData["ProductTitle"],
              description: menuData["Description"],
              defaultPrice: menuData["DefaultPrice"],
              isVeg: menuData["DefaultPrice"] == true ? 0 : 1,
              fileName:menuData["FileName"] != null ? menuData["FileName"] : "",
              image: menuData["Image"],
              categoryId: menuData["CategoryId"],
              toppings:menuData["Toppings"] != null ? menuData["Toppings"] : "",
              itemNo: menuData["ItemNo"],
              sizes: menuData["Sizes"],
              isActive: menuData["IsActive"] == true ? 0 : 1,
              isTopping: menuData["IsTopping"] == true ? 0 : 1,
              addedOn: menuData["AddedOn"].toString(),
              isDelete: menuData["IsDelete"] == true ? 0 : 1,
              quantity: menuData["quantity"]));
        }
        updateMenuDatabaseHelper.insert(data);  ////This is my SQFLITE database functionality where I want to add
```

```
Future<UpdateMenuModel> insert(UpdateMenuModel updateMenuModel) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient.insert('updateMenu', updateMenuModel.toJson());
    return updateMenuModel;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Future<void> insert(List<UpdateMenuModel> updateMenuModels) async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  final batch = dbClient.batch();
  for (var updateMenuModel in updateMenuModels) {
    batch.insert('updateMenu', updateMenuModel.toJson());
  }
  await batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: please check again I have add something

Answer (score 1):

**Simply because of your insert method is accepting one modal at a time but as you written was passing the whole list to that insert method so if you want to get rid of it you have loop through each value insert it one by one or if you want to add only last value then use can use data.last.**

Answer (score 0):

this will add the last added UpdateMenuModel from List

```
updateMenuDatabaseHelper.insert(data.last);
```